# Vb.net cannot convert string to system.uri

Tags: vb.net, string, file

I'm trying to make an FTP chat program. I've done it like 2 years ago, and I want to recreate it. It has a problem that it can't convert String to System.Uri as the first argument of the downloadfile command.

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("ftp://*le ftp link here*/c/log.txt", My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c\log.txt", "user", "pass", False, 30000)
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(New Uri("ftp://*le ftp link here*/c/log.txt"), My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c\log.txt", "user", "pass", False, 30000)
```

just say new Uri("")